# cannot resolve overloaded function... error

Tags: arduino-mega

I started to learn Arduino and I want to get an input from user to blink LEDs. I wrote under the void loop() section input codes. After i compiled it and Arduino IDE gave me this: "Arduino:1.8.5 (Windows 10), Kart:"Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560, ATmega2560 (Mega 2560)"

```
C:\Users\Yunus Emre ERYILMAZ\Documents\Arduino\sketch_feb17a\sketch_feb19a\sketch_feb19a.ino: In function 'void loop()':

sketch_feb19a:27: error: cannot resolve overloaded function 'parseInt' based on conversion to type 'int'

 numBlueBlink=Serial.parseInt;

             ^

sketch_feb19a:31: error: cannot resolve overloaded function 'parseInt' based on conversion to type 'int'

 numYellowBlink=Serial.parseInt;

               ^

exit status 1
cannot resolve overloaded function 'parseInt' based on conversion to type 'int'

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences."
```

What should i do, how can solve this problem? Thanks.

The code that i wrote:

```
int blueLEDPin=9;  // Declaring blue led's pin is 9.
int yellowLEDPin=10;  //Decllaring yellow led's pin is 10.
int blueOnTime=250;  // Bue led ontime
int blueOffTime=250; // Blue led offtime
int yellowOnTime=250; // Yellow led ontime
int yellowOffTime=250; // Yellow led offtime
int numBlueBlink=0;
int numYellowBlink=5;
String blueMessage="The blue LED is blinking...";
String yellowMessage="The yellow LED is blinking...";

void setup() { 
  String wm1 = "Welcome to";
  String wm2 = " My Program";
  String wm3;
  wm3 = wm1+wm2;
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println (wm3);
  pinMode (blueLEDPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode (yellowLEDPin, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
Serial.println ("How many times do you want the blue LED to blink? ");
while (Serial.available()==0){ }
numBlueBlink=Serial.parseInt;

Serial.println ("How many times do you want the yellow LED to blink? ");
while (Serial.available()==0){ }
numYellowBlink=Serial.parseInt;


Serial.println (blueMessage);
for (int j=1; j<=numBlueBlink; j=j+1) {
  Serial.print ("   You are on Blink #: ");
  Serial.println(j);
  digitalWrite (blueLEDPin,HIGH);  // Turn first led on
  delay (blueOnTime);  // Wait
  digitalWrite (blueLEDPin,LOW); // Turn first led off
  delay (blueOffTime); // Wait
}

Serial.println (" ");

Serial.println (yellowMessage);
for (int k=1; k<=numYellowBlink; k=k+1){
  Serial.print ("   You are on Blink #: ");
  Serial.println (k);
  digitalWrite (yellowLEDPin,HIGH); // Turn second led on
  delay (yellowOnTime); // Wait
  digitalWrite (yellowLEDPin,LOW);  // Turn second led off
  delay (yellowOffTime);  // Wait
}
Serial.println (" ");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function parseInt is a function and you have to add parameters with ( and ), even when it has no parameters, thus instead of

```
 numBlueBlink = Serial.parseInt;
```

you have to write

```
 numBlueBlink = Serial.parseInt();
```

See [Serial.parseInt](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ParseInt) for a reference.